# Connection to SSH server intermittently extremely slow/times out

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, timeout

I have two machines on a LAN; one runs Lubuntu 18.04 (call it the "server"), another one runs Devuan Beowulf (~= Debian Buster; call it the "client").

The server machine runs an SSH service on port 22. It's been running that for years, quite reliably (well, obviously, I occasionally upgrade the distro, but still - years).

For the past several months, I'm experiencing a strange phenomenon trying to ssh from the client to the server. If the connection gets established at all - everything works fine. But occasionally, and for a while (e.g. 5 minutes, 10 minutes, maybe more - but not a full day) - there's no response on that port. I've verified this is what happens using the `-vvv` switch with the ssh client.

What could be the reason for this happening?

Additional information:

- The LAN is wireless.
- Both machines are connected to the WLAN throughout this occurrence.
- I have good ping round-trips with no drops while this occurs.
- There are no other machines on the LAN other than the switch/router.
- To my knowledge, I'm not doing anything fishy over the network.
- I manage to SMB-mount shares on the server while this occurs.

Please ask for more details as necessary.

Comment: Did you also check `-vvv` on `sshd` (the server side)? What does it tell you?

Comment: Is the network issue only for sshd ?

Comment: @tonioc: Yes, see edit.

Comment: @Spiff: Will try this next time.

Comment: Sometimes, delay can because by reverse DNS attempts on server side (although I never experienced such long one). To remove this option you can set UseDNS=no on sshd_config and restart sshd. 
Also, you could monitor the port 22 with tcpdump on server side to see if connection is entering, and check logs.

Comment: @tonioc: Useful suggestion, will do this. Like you said, a bit unlikely this is the problem, but worth a shot.